# Dúvida storageAs Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Eu estava com o meu projeto Laravel local, e utilizo este código para salvar as minhas imagens:

```
$request->profile_photo->storeAs('empresas/perfil', $filename, 'public');
```

Agora eu hospedei meu projeto, para hospedar eu precisei tirar a pasta `public` da raiz do projeto, ela fica no mesmo nível do projeto e se chama `public_html`.

Na hora de salvar uma imagem apresenta o seguinte erro:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   fopen(/storage/ssd3/972/3511972/public_html): failed to open stream: Is a directory
>   in FilesystemAdapter.php (line 160)
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'fopen(/storage/ssd3/972/3511972/public_html): failed to open stream: Is a directory', '/storage/ssd3/972/3511972/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php', 160, array('path' => '../empresas/perfil', 'file' => object(UploadedFile), 'name' => 'Laravel_foto_perfiliuyuiwayeatgmailcom_teste.jpg', 'options' => array()))
>   at fopen('/storage/ssd3/972/3511972/public_html', 'r+')
>   in FilesystemAdapter.php (line 160)

O que eu preciso alterar para corrigir o problema??

Comment: Você configurou o `filesystem.php` na pasta `config`? e deu permissão de escrita na pastas?

Comment: `'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
`
Acho q o problema esta aqui mesmo, como eu faço pra ele pegar umas pasta que não esta na raiz do projeto?

Comment: `storage_path('app/public')` não deveria ser `storage_path('app/public_html')` quando a configuração muda tem que tomar cuidado com o total.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, e tentei várias outras e nada, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Deu permissão ... ???

Answer (score -1):

Muito provavelmente seu erro, assim como foi comigo, é relacionado ao tamanho da imagem que você está enviando ao servidor.

O php tem o o arquivo de configuração chamado `php.ini` e nele consta algumas configurações como o tamanho máximo do arquivo (`upload_max_filesize`, onde o valor padrão é 2MB) e o tamanho máximo da requisição feita usando o método POST (`post_max_size`, onde o valor padrão é 8MB).

Se sua imagem for maior que essas configurações o arquivo não estará disponível para que você o manuseie ou salve.

Dessa forma, o erro acontece quando o `fopen` é chamado internamente pelo método `storeAs` e utiliza o caminho real da imagem (`$file->getRealPath()`) que não está disponível por conta da limitação do tamanho da imagem.

Comment: Tente detalhar mais sua respostas